# If $z = \cos{2θ} + i \sin{2θ}$, prove that $\frac{2}{1+z} = 1 - i \tan{θ}$

Tags: complex-numbers

The title says it all I guess. I haven't really tried much with it because I honestly have no idea what to do.

If              $$Z = \cos{2θ} + i \sin{2θ}$$
 show that 
$$\frac{2}{1+Z} = 1-i \tan{θ}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac2{1+z}=\frac2{1+\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta}=\frac{2+2\cos2\theta-i2\sin2\theta}{(1+\cos2\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}=$$

$$=\frac{2+2\cos2\theta-i2\sin2\theta}{2(1+\cos2\theta)}=1-\frac{\sin2\theta}{1+\cos2\theta}i=1-\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}i=$$

$$=1-\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{2\cos^2\theta}i=1-i\tan\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t$ be $t=\tan \theta$; $$Z=\cos 2\theta+i\sin 2\theta=\frac{1-t^2+i2t}{1+t^2}$$

$$1+Z=\frac{1-t^2+2it+1+t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac{2+2it}{1+t^2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+Z}=\frac{1+t^2}{2(1+it)}$$

$$\frac{2}{1+Z}=\frac{(1+t^2)(1-it)}{1+t^2}=1-it=1-i\tan \theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $w=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ then $z = w^2$ and $\bar w = \cos \theta - i \sin \theta = \frac{1}{w}$. The equality becomes:

$$\frac{2}{1+w^2}=\frac{\bar w}{\frac{1}{2}(w + \bar w)} = \frac{2}{w(w+\bar w)}=\cdots$$