# Given that $z = \cos{θ} + i \sin{θ}$ where z ≠ -1, show that $\frac{2}{1+z} = 1 - i \tan(\frac{θ}{2})$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given that $z = \cos{θ} + i \sin{θ}$ where z ≠ -1, show that $\frac{2}{1+z} = 1 - i \tan(\frac{θ}{2})$

$$ \frac{2}{1+z} = \frac{2}{1 +\cos\,(θ) + i\,sin\,(θ)} $$

$$\text{since} \quad z \,=\, \cos,(θ) + i\,\sin\,(θ) $$

$$ \frac{2}{1 + \cos\,(θ) + i\,\sin\,(θ)} \,*\, \frac{1 + \cos\,(θ) − i\,\sin\,(θ)}{1 + \cos\,(θ) − i\,\sin\,(θ)} $$

Which can be re-written as:
$$ \frac{2\,[\,1 + cos\,(θ) − i\,sin\,(θ)\,]}{[\,1 + cos\,(θ)\,]^2 - i^2\,sin^2 (θ)} $$

$$ \frac{2\,[\,1 + \cos\,(θ) − i\,\sin\,(θ)\,]}{1 + 2\,\cos\,(θ) + \cos^2 (θ) + \sin^2 (θ)} $$

Using... $\quad cos^2 (θ) + sin^2 (θ) = 1 $

$$ \frac{2\,[\,1 + \cos\,(θ) − i\,\sin\,(θ)\,]}{2 + 2\,\cos\,(θ)} \,=\, \frac{2\,[\,1 + \cos\,(θ) − i\,sin\,(θ)\,]}{2\,[\,1 + \cos\,(θ)]} \,=\, \frac{1 + \cos\,(θ) − i\,\sin\,(θ)}{1 + \cos\,(θ)} $$

Using... $\quad 1 + \cos(θ) \,≡\, 2\,\cos^2 (\frac{θ}{2})$

And... $\quad sin (θ) \,≡\, 2\,\sin (\frac{θ}{2})\,\cos (\frac{θ}{2}) $

$$ \frac{2\,cos\frac{θ}{2}\,[\,\cos (\frac{θ}{2}) − i\,\sin (\frac{θ}{2})\,]\,}{2\,\cos^2 (\frac{θ}{2})} \,=\, \frac{\cos (\frac{θ}{2}) − i\sin (\frac{θ}{2})}{\cos (\frac{θ}{2})} \,=\, 1 - i\,\tan (\frac{θ}{2})$$

A related question on Mathematics Stack Exchange can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036579/if-z-cos2%CE%B8-i-sin2%CE%B8-prove-that-frac21z-1-i-tan%CE%B8/2036586#2036586).

Comment: Okay so what is your question?

Comment: The question you reference is a complete duplicate, and there are better solutions there, especially @Piquito's one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $z = \cos{2θ} + i \sin{2θ}$, prove that $\frac{2}{1+z} = 1 - i \tan{θ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036579/if-z-cos2%ce%b8-i-sin2%ce%b8-prove-that-frac21z-1-i-tan%ce%b8)

Comment: In short $$\frac2{1+z}=\frac2{1+e^{i\theta}}=\frac{e^{-i\frac{\theta}2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}2}= 1-i\tan\frac{\theta}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $z = \cos{θ} + i \sin{θ}$ where $z \neq -1$, show that $\frac{2}{1+z} = 1 - i \tan(\frac{θ}{2})$

First, I would note that $\tan\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}$ and $z =e^{i\theta}= \cos{θ} + i \sin{θ}$ , so $$\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}{1+e^{i\theta}}=\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)$$

Next, there are a few properties and a formula we should know.

- $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$
- $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$
- De Moivre's Formula: $[\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)]^n=\cos(n\theta)+\sin(n\theta)$

In our scenario, we note that $\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{θ}{2}\right)$ and analogously $-\sin\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)=\sin\left(-\frac{θ}{2}\right)$. Hence, by applying De Moivre's law, $\cos\left(-\frac{θ}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{θ}{2}\right)\rightarrow \left[\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Using the following properties, we can rewrite the equation as such: $$\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{θ}{2}\right)}{1+e^{i\theta}}=\left[\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
\frac{2\cos(\frac{θ}{2})}{1+e^{i\theta}}=e^{i(-\frac{\theta}{2})}\\2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=e^{i(-\frac{\theta}{2})}+e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

Expanding: $$2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\left(\cos\frac{-\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{-\theta}{2}\right)+\left(cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+i\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\right)\\
2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\
\therefore 2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @Quanto posted a comment 1h ago.

Comment: Also, why is your last set of equations concluding $x=x$?